# Issue with StreamBuilder and streams in Flutter (receiving duplicated data)

Tags: flutter, stream, duplicates, stream-builder, sink

today I have faced a problem with streams and StreamBuilder.
The problem is the following:
If you have multiple StreamBuilder widgets listening to the same stream, and you add data into its sink, this data will go out through the stream the amount of StreamBuilder listeners that you have, in other words:
If you have one StreamController (or BehaviorSubject) , k amount of widgets of type StreamBuilder, and you try to do StreamController.sink.add(event), this event will go out k times trough the stream, one per StreamBuilder.
Is that an expected behavior (expected behavoir = input an event and listening just once from the other side independentlly of the amount of listeners) ? I was able to "fix" this encapsulating almost all the widget tree into one StreamBuilder, but this isnt as optimal as the first approach because of you are rendering the whole tree instead of some little node widgets.
Here I left some code to test it if you want (This code is a modification of *flutter create project_name* project).
Thank you!
(P.D: This works well if you just listen the streams without StreamBuilder, i.e: streamController.stream.listen..)

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:rxdart/subjects.dart';

class MyAppBloc with ChangeNotifier {
  int _currentIndex;
  BehaviorSubject<bool> _controller;

  MyAppBloc() {
    _currentIndex = 0;
    _controller = BehaviorSubject<bool>();
  }

  Stream<int> get currentIndex => _controller.stream.map<int>((event) {
        print('[event: $event]');
        _currentIndex++;
        return _currentIndex;
      });

  StreamSink<bool> get increment => _controller.sink;

  void close() {
    _controller.close();
  }
}
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:test_project/bloc/my_app_bloc.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;
  Widget leadingBuilder(MyAppBloc bloc) {
    return StreamBuilder<int>(
      initialData: 0,
      stream: bloc.currentIndex,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<int> snapshot) {
        print('[leadingBuilderSnapshot: $snapshot]');
        return Text(snapshot.data.toString());
      },
    );
  }

  StreamBuilder<int> counterBuilder(MyAppBloc bloc) {
    return StreamBuilder<int>(
      initialData: 0,
      stream: bloc.currentIndex,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<int> snapshot) {
        print('[counterBuilderSnapshot: $snapshot]');
        return Text(
          snapshot.data.toString(),
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('[build]');
    final _bloc = Provider.of<MyAppBloc>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: Container(
          width: 30,
          height: 30,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: leadingBuilder(_bloc),
        ),
        title: Text(title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            StreamBuilder<int>(
              initialData: 0,
              stream: _bloc.currentIndex,
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<int> snapshot) {
                return Text('${snapshot.data}');
              },
            ),
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            counterBuilder(_bloc),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => _bloc.increment.add(true),
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I didn't understand your question / explanation, you entered the number 1 and received a different number in each streambuilder (because you are doing the increment inside your stream and it is logical to happen) or you expected to receive the number 1 in all streambuilder?

Comment: Im just adding true to the sink to trigger the increment event, Im starting with 0 and when I receive the state to display it into the view, it displays 2, then 4, then... Its like its being incremented in two the index and I dont understand why that happens, because I just add one event to the sink, it's supposed to output one state and therefore will increment in one, isn it?

Comment: this happens because the increment is in the streambuilder's get, so every time it is called the increment is executed. Instead of calling the sink, call a function in the bloc that increments it and adds it to the sink.

Comment: Yes, that workaround works fine, but what I dont understand is why if I add just one event to the sink, its being  processed twice in this case. The flow that I imagine is adding one event, processing the data, and listen that single state in each listener, but this behavior its like I add one event per listener

Comment: you added the increment in the streambuilder's get, so every time the streambuilder receives the instruction to be updated he fetches the stream (he gets the stream) and then the increment happens .. if you have n streambuilders, he will do n gets and n increments.

Comment: Maybe I am missunderstandig how it works internally the flow of the streambuilder.
Thank you for your explanation and time Claudio!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `currentIndex` is a getter and you are using `map()`, a new stream will be created every time
you call `bloc.currentIndex` and `StreamBuilder` will listen to it.

So in original code , there are actually 1 `StreamControlller`, and k `Streams`. (k: number of `StreamBuilder`)

To solve your problem, you can create an eventController, and listen to it inside a bloc to execute your logic. (eventStream is listened from only bloc itself, it will be created just once)

for example:

```dart
class MyAppBloc {
  MyAppBloc() {
    _eventController.listen((event) {
      print('[event: $event]');
      _indexController.add(currentIndex.value + 1);
    });
  }

  final _indexController = BehaviorSubject<int>.seeded(0);
  final _eventController = PublishSubject<bool>();

  ValueStream<int> get currentIndex => _indexController.stream;
  StreamSink<bool> get increment => _eventController.sink;

  void close() {
    _indexController?.close();
    _eventController?.close();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use 2 streams/sink and put the increment outside the get stream.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:rxdart/subjects.dart';

class Bloc {
  int _counter = 0;

  Bloc() {
    _controller.stream.listen(_incrementStream);
  }

  final _counterStream = BehaviorSubject<int>.seeded(0);

  Stream get presentCounter => _counterStream.stream;
  Sink get _addValue => _counterStream.sink;

  StreamController _controller = BehaviorSubject<bool>();
  StreamSink<bool> get incrementCounter => _controller.sink;

  void _incrementStream(data) {
    _counter += 1;
    _addValue.add(_counter);
  }

  void dispose() {
    _counterStream.close();
    _controller.close();
  }
}



import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:increment/bloc.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Bloc _bloc = Bloc();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            StreamBuilder<int>(
                stream: _bloc.presentCounter,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  return Text(
                    '${snapshot.data}',
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                  );
                }),
            SizedBox(
              height: 60,
            ),
            StreamBuilder<int>(
                stream: _bloc.presentCounter,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  return Text(
                    '${snapshot.data}',
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
                  );
                }),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          _bloc.incrementCounter.add(true);
        },
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```